# IGraph/M: How to understand IGMotifs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages

There is a function `IGMotifs` in package of [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). I have read it some times but fail to understand it.

```
SeedRandom[1]
g = RandomGraph[{5, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGMotifs[g, 3]
```

> `{Indeterminate,Indeterminate,5,3}`

Or a disconnected graph

```
SeedRandom[2]
g = RandomGraph[{8, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As the documentation, the `IGTriadCensus` serve this case.

> To count non-connected size-3 subgraphs, use IGTriadCensus.

Then I get a result like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well,I have lose my directory totally..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `IGMotifs` is to find [graph motifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_motif).  Currently size-3 and size-4 motifs are supported, both directed and undirected.  Usually, this function is used with directed graphs.

#### What are motifs?

Let us look at size-3 directed graphs. There are 16 of these if we do not count isomorphisms. They can be shown using

```
<<IGraphM`

Grid[Partition[IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 3}], 4], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

The connectivity pattern of any 3 nodes in a directed graph will fall into one of these 16 categories. I.e., the subgraph induced by those three nodes will be isomorphic with one of the 16 3-vertex graphs above.

`IGMotifs[g, 3]` simply counts how many times each of these 16 patterns appear in a graph.

For example,

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "MetabolicNetworkAeropyrumPernix"}];

DirectedGraphQ[g]
(* True *)

IGMotifs[g, 3]
(* {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 3221, Indeterminate, 7399, 200, 3538, 0, 0, 219, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

The counts are returned in the same order as the graphs in `IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 3}]`.

What are those `Indeterminate`s there?  The algorithm ([RAND-ESU](http://theinf1.informatik.uni-jena.de/publications/network-motifs-wabi05.pdf)) [used by igraph](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Motifs.html#idm470928998848) can only count weakly connected subgraphs.  Notice that above subgraphs no. 1, 2 and 4 are not connected.  Counts are not returned for these.  Thus the 1st, 2nd and 4th elements will always be `Indeterminate` when counting directed 3-motifs.

In hindsight, using `Missing[]` would have been better than `Indeterminate`, but I do not think I will change this now to preserve compatibility.

If we want to count all 16 possible subgraphs, we can use `IGTriadCensus`.

```
IGTriadCensus[g]
(* <|"003" -> 18942639, "012" -> 524169, "102" -> 6889, 
 "021D" -> 3538, "021U" -> 3221, "021C" -> 7399, "111D" -> 200, 
 "111U" -> 219, "030T" -> 0, "030C" -> 0, "201" -> 6, "120D" -> 0, 
 "120U" -> 0, "120C" -> 0, "210" -> 0, "300" -> 0|> *)
```

This returns an association with same strange looking keys.  These are "MAN labels" where MAN stands for Mutual, Asymmetric, None, i.e. bidirectional connection, unidirectional connection or no connection. `012` means that there are no bidirectional connections, 1 unidirectional one, and two unconnected pairs, i.e. this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This type of notation for size-3 directed graphs [is sometimes used in sociology](http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED024086.pdf).  I have no personal need for this notation.  I am simply mirroring the approach of the original igraph in IGraph/M.

You can find out what label corresponds to what 3-vertex directed graph using

```
IGData["MANTriadLabels"]
```

[image]

You can get size-3 induced subgraph counts in the same format as `IGMotifs` returns them, but with the missing entries filled in, using:

```
Lookup[IGTriadCensus[g], Keys@IGData["MANTriadLabels"]]
(* {18942639, 524169, 3221, 6889, 7399, 200, 3538, 0, 0, 219, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

The triad counts will sum up to the total number of triplets in the graph:

```
Total[%]
(* 19488280 *)

Binomial[VertexCount[g], 3]
(* 19488280 *)
```

If you want to learn more about the applications of motifs, take a look at [Uri Alon's website](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/mcb/UriAlon/research/network-motifs), [Milo et. al](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.298.5594.824) and check the example in the IGraph/M documentation.

People typically look at subgraphs that occur much more frequently in some type of network than they would in a random network with the same degree sequence.  For example, in our network `g` the following size-4 subgraphs occur more than 3 times as often as expected:

```
pos = Position[
  N@IGMotifs[g, 4]/IGMotifs[IGRewire[g, 1000000], 4],
  x_?NumericQ /; x > 3
  ]
(* {{20}, {67}, {129}, {147}} *)

Extract[IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 4}], pos]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks,I understand it eventually..